# Merging multiple DFs in R, searching for similarities

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I currently have 3 `data.frames` of information that I would like to merge together. Each data frame is the output of a variant analysis workflow, so all of the column names are similar. I have created a specific column entitled `Variant_ID` that I am interested in merging by. Essentially, this `Variant_ID` contains a unique barcode for each row in that sample specific `data.frame`. Also due to the nature of the work, it's possible that there is overlap between the three data frames, meaning while one barcode is unique in `data.frame.1`, it may also exist in `data.frame.2`. I also have a column in each df that contains its sample origin.

I would like to merge the three data frames and find the overlapping `Variant_ID`s. If two `Variant_ID`s overlap in two or more dfs, then the sample origin value should be set to "shared."

For example:

```
DF1
   
   Start   Stop   ...  Variant_ID   Sample_Origin
1  71      72.        71_72_...        A
2  7562    7563       7562_7563...     A
3  8824    8825       8824_8825...     A
```

```
DF2
   
   Start   Stop   ...  Variant_ID   Sample_Origin
1  95      96         95_96_...        B
2  7562    7563       7562_7563...     B
3  8824    8825       8824_8825...     B
```

```
DF3
   
   Start   Stop   ...  Variant_ID   Sample_Origin
1  9994    9995       9994_9995_...      C
2  7562    7563       7562_7563...       C
3  3323    3324       3323_3324...       C
```

The resulting DF would look like such:

```
Final
   
   Start   Stop   ...  Variant_ID   Sample_Origin
1  71      72         71_72_...        A
2  7562    7563       7562_7563...     shared
3  8824    8825       8824_8825...     shared
4  95      96         95_96_...        B
5  9994    9995       9994_9995_...    C
6  7562    7563       7562_7563...     shared
7  3323    3324       3323_3324...     C
```

I've thought about using `mutate`, `merge`, `lapply`, and other functions, but I'm failing in trying to find an efficient way to complete this task. Any suggestions and help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why not `rbind` all data frames together, then, assuming the new data frame is called "combo_df" use dplyr to do: `combo_df %>% group_by(Variant_ID) %>% mutate(Sample_Origin_new = ifelse(n() == 1, Sample_Origin, 'shared') )`

Comment: trows 2 and 6 of the desired output match.. is this intentional, or a type?. When intentional, please explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it seems that you would want to simply bind the dataframes together.
If I understand your question correctly, you then want to update the `Sample_Origin` column if there is more than one match, right?

This can easily be done, using `n()` on the grouping by `Variant_ID` to count whether more than one sample source is present.

```
library(dplyr)

final <- bind_rows(DF1, DF2, DF3) %>%
  group_by(Variant_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Sample_Origin = ifelse(n() > 1, 'shared', Sample_Origin)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

You may want to use `n_distinct(Sample_Origin) > 1`, if the same `Variant_ID` could appear more than once within any of the individual source dataframes.
In that case, you would make sure to only mark a variant sample as `'shared'` when it really appears in more than one sample dataframe.

This obviously leaves you with multiple duplicate entries, as you have also shared in your expected output.
If that is not a problem (and also there is no issue with different `Start` and `Stop` values to handle) then the above snippet should help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what you try to achieve?

```
library( data.table)
DF1 <- fread("Start   Stop    Variant_ID   Sample_Origin
  71      72.        71_72_...        A
  7562    7563       7562_7563...     A
  8824    8825       8824_8825...     A")

DF2 <- fread("Start   Stop     Variant_ID   Sample_Origin
  95      96         95_96_...        B
  7562    7563       7562_7563...     B
  8824    8825       8824_8825...     B")

DF3 <- fread("Start   Stop     Variant_ID   Sample_Origin
  9994    9995       9994_9995_...      C
  7562    7563       7562_7563...       C
  3323    3324       3323_3324...       C")


DT <- rbindlist( list( DF1, DF2, DF3 ) )
unique( DT[ DT[, if(.N>1) .SD, by=Variant_ID], Sample_Origin := "shared", on = .(Variant_ID) ] )

#    Start Stop    Variant_ID Sample_Origin
# 1:    71   72     71_72_...             A
# 2:  7562 7563  7562_7563...        shared
# 3:  8824 8825  8824_8825...        shared
# 4:    95   96     95_96_...             B
# 5:  9994 9995 9994_9995_...             C
# 6:  3323 3324  3323_3324...             C
```

output is not exaclty matching your desired output.. but it's not clear to me why rows 2 and 6 are identical in your desired output.

If you do not want to delete any rows, but just want to mark them as `shared', drip` unique()`.

```
DT[ DT[, if(.N>1) .SD, by=Variant_ID], Sample_Origin := "shared", on = .(Variant_ID) ][]

#    Start Stop    Variant_ID Sample_Origin
# 1:    71   72     71_72_...             A
# 2:  7562 7563  7562_7563...        shared
# 3:  8824 8825  8824_8825...        shared
# 4:    95   96     95_96_...             B
# 5:  7562 7563  7562_7563...        shared
# 6:  8824 8825  8824_8825...        shared
# 7:  9994 9995 9994_9995_...             C
# 8:  7562 7563  7562_7563...        shared
# 9:  3323 3324  3323_3324...             C
```